# IIS Server-Level http authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, http-authentication

we have a staging server that we would like to restrict visits to it unless the client passes Http Basic authentication challenge, if all goes well, the client should be able to navigate the site,if the user goes to a page that requires authentication (we are using forms authentication), the user should be treated as not authenticated , is that even possible?

the main reason behind this is that we don't want Google or any other Search engines to index anything on the server.

i have read many ways to implement this (basic http,robots.txt,noindex,etc...), the problem with these -if i have understood it correctly- is that they require changes to the application.

So is that possible? if not , what are your recommendations?

Comment: So you already have forms authentication on your app and you want to add some other authentication on top of it?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking to prevent Bots from accessing the staging server

Comment: You should turn on basic authentication in IIS and see if it does what you want.  If it doesn't, then update your question with more details.